# Python: condensing arbitrarily large dataframe query

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, combinations, list-comprehension

I am using a pandas dataframe, and am iterating over all possible combinations of values in several columns.  I do this using `itertools.combinations` and `pandas.Series.unique()`:

```
query_fields = ['direction','subj_id','speed']
query_items = [df_reps[k].unique() for k in query_fields]

for a in itertools.product(*query_items):
    df = df_reps[(df_reps['subj_id']==a[0]) & (df_reps['direction']==a[1]) & (df_reps['speed']==a[2])]
    #Do something with df
```

I'm wondering if there is a more pythonic way of condensing my dataframe query.  If I had more possibly query fields then this approach would become increasingly unusable.  One possible method is to iterate over all the fields and apply each query individually (like a funnel) - could this be done with list comprehension, something like:

```
df = df_reps[(df_reps[qf]==a[i]) for qf,i in enumerate(query_fields)] #Doesn't work
```

Does this functionality already exist in pandas?

### EDIT

**Input**: A `DataFrame` and a list containing headers.

**Output**: A loop or similiar, selecting each unique combination of values in the columns specified by the header list.

Comment: You aren't using pandas.DataFrame.unique, you are using pandas.Series.unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of "*iterating over all possible combinations of values in several columns*" can be easily solved using pandas [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).
Essentially you create groups based on the values of all the columns and then you retrieve the part of the data where each sequence occurs. No loops involved, it is a one-liner.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,4, (100, 5)),
                  columns = ['direction','subj_id','speed','other1', 'other2'])

fields = ['direction','subj_id','speed']  

grouped_by_values = df.groupby(fields)
queries_results = {key: group for key, group in grouped_by_values }
```

Here is an example of the results:

```
for key, group in queries_results.iteritems():
#for key, group in grouped_by_values:  #Equivalent, probably better

    print key, group


(1, 1, 1)     direction  subj_id  speed  other1  other2
3           1        1      1       3       3
37          1        1      1       2       3
48          1        1      1       2       1
52          1        1      1       1       3
81          1        1      1       1       1
97          1        1      1       1       1
(1, 1, 2)     direction  subj_id  speed  other1  other2
25          1        1      2       2       3
62          1        1      2       3       1
```

If instead you want to know how to "*condense dataframe queries*", here is an approach: generate a list of [boolean masks](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) (one for each condition) and then generating the intersection using [reduce](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce).

Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Reproducible Example
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,4, (100, 3)), columns = ['A', 'B', 'C'])
query_fields = ['A','B','C']
query_items = [1,2,3]

# Individual masks
ind_masks = [df[key].eq(val) for key, val in zip(query_fields, query_items)]
# Combined Query
mask = reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, ind_masks)

query_result = df[mask]
```

Comment: Answer updated using list containing headers as input.

Answer (score 0):

use pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates;

```
unique_df = df_reps.drop_duplicates(['direction','subj_id','speed'])
```

You now have a new dataframe that you can continue to slice by other conditions, like;

```
unique_df[unique_df['direction'] == 'left']
```

Comment: Although this may be a better solution for determining these combinations, I think you may have misinterpreted my question.  I am trying to find a way of "slicing" the dataframe without having to manually list each query as you have done - I have them stored in a list, I was hoping to leverage that in some sort of comprehension.

Comment: It's hard to know what exactly you are trying to do without an expected input and a desired output, because what you have written is hard to follow without context. You refer to a `df_reps` and a `rep_df` without ever declaring what those look like to begin with, so there isn't really a way for me to infer what's going on.

Comment: I realize I was a little vague, my apologies - I have made some edits to hopefully clarify :)

Comment: Yeah, this still doesn't make sense. `query_items` is a list of pd.Series objects, which you are getting the Cartesian product for, which for all intents and purposes is the same as the `unique_df` I just showed you. Then you are repeatedly assigning `df` to a slice of the original df matching elements of the product, which came from the orignal df in the first place, so you are just going in circles. If you don't offer an expected input with a desired output, we are all grasping at straws here.

Comment: it sounds like you want pd.DataFrame.groupby though